# How to check if a column value is updated/modified

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check if the logout_date column is updated. If it was updated then I have to modify the salary column.

| login_time | logout_time | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 11:12:30 | 2021-08-24 14:34:56 | 1234 |

I have to check if the logout_time is updated, if it was updated then the salary would be 4567.

| login_time | logout_time | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 11:12:30 | 2021-08-24 19:30:00 | 4567 |

If the logout_time is not updated, then the salary would be same i.e., 1234

| login_time | logout_time | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 11:12:30 | 2021-08-24 14:34:56 | 1234 |

I have written below query, but i am not getting the required output.

```
select salary ,case when "logout_time" is updated then salary  = new_salary from abc;
```

Can someone help me with the query
Can someone please help me with the query.

Comment: Does that query run without an error?

Comment: How do you know if the logout_time column is updated?

Comment: Where does new_salary come from?

Comment: new_salary value will be retrieved from other table. There is seperate script which will be running to update logout_time

Comment: I have to check if logout_time column is updated or not. I need help on this.

Comment: Looks like you need a trigger to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

A column holds one value at a time, you cannot do what you want in a SQL statement (you can only say what is the logout time).

To work this out you need two values to compare.   What you haven't said is how you are identifying an update.   Is it any change after a point in time, is it each and every update, is it the first update after a particular point in time ...

The key here is you need to determine the logic to identify an update.   Below are a number of options to then identify the changes.

## Static Point In Time Comparision

If you are comparing against a static list (ie. you pick a point in time and any changes after that meet you criteria) then you could create a copy of the table with a `CTAS` statement and then run a query to join this snapshot table and the real one on some ID where the logout_time columns are different.

## Trigger

If you want an event based update (ie. you want to know each and every time logout_time changes) then this can be accomplished with a trigger but we wary as triggers come with quite an overhead.

## Flashback Query

Depending on your database setup and retention periods you might be able to run a flashback query to get older data.   This isn't necessarily guaranteed so you would need to know what you are doing to use this.

`SELECT * FROM myTable as of TIMESTAMP(sysdate - 0.5)` would give you the contents of the table as of 12 hours ago which you could compare to the current value.